# How do I force NetBeans to update a Java package via Subversion?

Tags: svn, netbeans

We are using NetBeans (6.9.1) and Subversion.  On my local machine, I have dozens of `locally modified` files.  However, the problem is that I never modified those file!  At least not that I can tell.  I mean, I didn't open the file and change anything in them.

Now, when I do a `Update` it won't pull down the changes.  When I do a `diff`, I get this as the `BASE` file:

```
<property name="transactiontype" type="string">
    <column name="transactiontype" length="25" />
</property>
```

And this as the "locally modified file"

```
<property name="transactiontype" type="string">
    <column name="transactiontype" />
</property>
```

Notice it's missing the length attribute.  That is just one of many examples.  The remote is correct.  But update does nothing.  I even tried to revert changes to the last commit.  Still the same.

How can I tell NB/Subversion to destroy my local file with whatever is in the remote?  I'm afraid that if I do it manually I might mess up the remote.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, the answer was to completely wipe my project off (after a backup) and re-import the whole thing.  Not sure why it the changes wouldn't be pulled down.